# MySQL ADO.Net Nested DataReaders

Tags: c#, mysql, nested, ado.net, datareader

I want to retrieve a list of accounts with one SQL statement, and then loop through them while running more SQL statements. When I try to, I get this error:

> Unhandled Exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Here's an example:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("host=..."))
{

    connection.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand cmdAccounts = connection.CreateCommand())
    {

        cmdAccounts.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM accounts";

        using (MySqlDataReader accounts = cmdAccounts.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (accounts.Read())
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Account {0}:", account.GetString("name"));

                using (MySqlCommand cmdPictures = connection.CreateCommand())
                {

                    cmdPictures.CommandText = "SELECT id, width, height FROM pictures WHERE account_id = @accountId";
                    cmdPictures.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountId", accounts.GetInt32("id"));

                    using (MySqlDataReader pictures = cmdPictures.ExecuteReader())
                    {

                        while (pictures.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\tPicture #{0}: {1} x {2}", pictures.GetInt32("id"), picture2.GetInt32("width"), picture2.GetInt32("height"));
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to use a DataSet, or is there a way to do this in MySQL with just DataReaders?

Comment: You need to use two connections and link the two commands to the two connections. As far as I know MySql doesn't have the [MultipleActiveResultSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/multiple-active-result-sets-mars) option in its connectionstring keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with DataReaders, but you will need a separate connection object for both levels of reader:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("host=..."))
using (MySqlCommand cmdAccounts = MySqlCommand("SELECT id, name FROM accounts" , connection))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection("host=..."))
    using (MySqlCommand cmdPictures = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id, width, height FROM pictures WHERE account_id = @accountId", connection2))
    using (MySqlDataReader accounts = cmdAccounts.ExecuteReader())
    {
        cmdPictures.Parameters.Add("@accountId", MySqlDbType.Int32); 
        connection2.Open()

        while (accounts.Read())
        {    
            Console.WriteLine("Account {0}:", account.getString("name"));

            cmdPictures.Parameters["@accountId"].Value = accounts.GetInt32("id");

            using (MySqlDataReader pictures = cmdPictures.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (pictures.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tPicture #{0}: {1} x {2}", pictures.GetInt32("id"), picture2.GetInt32("width"), picture2.GetInt32("height"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But even as much better as this is, it's still the wrong way to think about the problem in the first place. You really want to **JOIN** the two tables in the database:

```
string sql = 
    "SELECT a.id as AccountID, a.name, p.id as PictureID, p.width, p.height" + 
    " FROM accounts a" +
    " INNER JOIN pictures p on p.account_id = a.id" +
    " ORDER BY a.name, a.id";

using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("host=..."))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        bool reading = rdr.Read();
        while (reading)
        {
            int CurrentAccount = rdr.GetInt32("AccountId");
            Console.WriteLine("Account {0}:", rdr.GetString("name"));

            while (reading && CurrentAccount == rdr.GetInt32("AccountId"))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("\tPicture #{0}: {1} x {2}", 
                 rdr.GetInt32("PictureId"), rdr.GetInt32("width"), rdr.GetInt32("height"));
               reading = rdr.Read();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't fill a datatable with SqlDataAdapter?
 then, foreach row in datatable, extract second sql command and display the dates? 
Is just an opinion from a beginner, try it or check for more answers